# Javascript simulation

Tags: javascript, scrape

I am doing a webscrape on this public website, http://www.windfinder.com.

I am trying to simulate what the "Save changes button" does at http://www.windfinder.com/settings, can't figure out what the javascript does to save the setting.

I've tried firebug and tamper data but I can't find it!

Any help is appreciated!

---

Additional Information:

Im using a C# application to try and do what the "Save changes button" is doing. Like maybe setting it in the http headers or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says right inside the source code.  Whenever one of the buttons are clicked, it saves the selection using the `storemanager` object which is an instance of `UnitsManager`.  The `UnitsManager` comes from the minified source code on cloudfront which seems to store the settings into `localStorage` on `localStorage` compatible browsers using the cookiename (`wf_units`).

You can see all your setting changes by typing: `localStorage.getItem('wf_units');`

Comment: hi simonleojung, thanks for the answer. the wf_units isn't stored in the cookies response/request headers do you know where it is stored?

Comment: I don't really have the time to look through the `UnitsManager` source but, I'm pretty sure for modern browsers they are just using `localStorage` and falling back to cookies when not supported.

You can probably have a look into the source and verify.

Answer (score 0):

the click event is registered in the javascript

```
 $('#settings-submit').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.alert').show();
      window.setTimeout(function(){
        var redirect = document.referrer ? document.referrer : '/';
        window.location.href = redirect;
      }, 1500);
    });
```

[image: screenshot of cookie]

Comment: any idea where it's stored? i check the cookies request/response headers and can't find it there.

Comment: added a screen shot of what the cookies look like in chrome's dev tools

Comment: The values that were set (namely temperature, wind speed, etc) isn't in the screenshot u uploaded.